# auto generating www folder with no of zip files cause app data increase to 180 mb

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

When i building for android native environment using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 it creates a no of zip files under www folder that cause app data size increased to more than 100 mb.

Comment: Try to be more specific in your description - add a proper description of "no of zip files" either by text and/or screen shot.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default no .zip files are created by MobileFirst, and certainly not ones that reach 180MB, in the generated native project.

The only instance in which a .zip file will be created is when setting the"encryptWebResources" option in application-descriptor.xml to "true" in which case the entirety of the www folder will be a .zip file. If this is actually what you've done and this reaches 180MB, then those 180MB are actually *your project* and you need to check why you have so many, and if you need them all.

If this does not answer your question, edit your question and provide a better explanation.